# How I can create custom tool type for panels Header?

Tags: extjs

I want to create tool type like maximize or minimize:

```
{
        type: 'my-type-name',
        tooltip: 'Make Toolbar Float',
        listeners: {
            click: function(panel , e , owner , eOpts){}
}
```

To achive that I already created class in Tool.scss  as in theme-base

```
.#{$prefix}tool-tool-type-my-type-name{
    @include icon($tool-my-type-name-icon);
}
```

But icon is private mixin and in Tool.scss not visible.
After that I created own declaration of that class:

```
 .#{$prefix}tool-tool-type-my-type-name{
    content: $fa-var-external-link;
    font-family: $font-icon-font-family;
    font-size: $tool-glyph-font-size;
    color: red;
    width:$tool-glyph-font-size;
    height:$tool-glyph-font-size;
}
```

That didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

in var/...Tool.scss

```
// custom icons:
$tool-my-type-name-glyph: dynamic($fa-var-external-link $tool-glyph-font-size $font-icon-font-family);
```

in src.../Tools.scss

```
  .#{$prefix}tool-my-type-name {
        @if $enable-font-icons and $tool-my-type-name-glyph != null) {
            @include font-icon($tool-my-type-name-glyph);
            background: none;
        } @else {
            background-position: 0 ($tool-size * -2);
        }
    }
```